# Waterline changing values at start of application

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, waterline

When ever I start my application which uses Waterline for its database ORM the password field in the users table gets changed. I assume it is re-hashing it but I can't see why it would be doing it.

My Collection looks like this:

```
Crypto = require 'crypto'
Waterline = require 'waterline'

module.exports = Waterline.Collection.extend({
  identity: 'users'
  connection: 'default'
  attributes: {
    id: {
      type: 'integer'
      autoIncrement: true
      primaryKey: true
    }
    name: {
      type: 'string'
      required: true
    }
    username: {
      type: 'string'
      unique: true
      required: true
    }
    password: {
      type: 'string'
      required: true
    }

    verifyPassword: (password) ->
      md5 = Crypto.createHash('md5')
      md5.update(password)
      (@password == md5.digest('hex'))
  }

  beforeCreate: (attrs, cb) ->
    md5 = Crypto.createHash('md5')
    md5.update(attrs.password)
    attrs.password = md5.digest('hex')
    cb()

  authenticate: (username, password, cb) ->
    @findOne({username: username}).then (user) ->
      if user
        if user.verifyPassword(password)
          cb(null, user)
        else
          cb("Incorrect password given for #{username}", null)
      else
        cb("Unable to find user #{username}", null)

})
```

`createdAt` and `updatedAt` gets set to the current time but thing else in the record changes.

I am using a PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Just a heads up, md5 is **absolutely wrong** for password hashing. It is literally useless.

Comment: Yeah this is an app still in early development I used it as a quick proof of concept but will be moving to bcrypt before its released